# How do I multiply each element in an array with a large number without getting OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, numpy

I'm writing a program where I want to multiply each number in an array (from numpy) with a big number (`1.692287392646066e+41`) and I do it like this:

```
x = array([ 16,  18,  19,  15,  27,  26,  13,  34,  38,  36,  43,  42,  48,
    50,  55,  57,  70,  67,  65,  85,  99,  94,  90, 112, 126, 130,
   142, 120])
weight = 1.692287392646066e+41

x[:] = [i*weight for i in x]
```

But then I recieve the error "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long". The strange thing is that multiplying the numbers outside the for loop seems to work:

```
In [1]: x[0]*weight
Out[1]: 2.7076598282337055e+42
```

My question is then, is there any way for me to do this inside a for loop, since I don't know beforehand how long my array is? (I know it has 1 row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command with shallow copy (`s[:]`) will create a view of `s` for you that its elements are type of `int` so after assignment it tries to assign the elements created by `[i*weight for i in s]` to `int` container but as your result are C long it raise the following error  :

```
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

If you just use `[i*weight for i in s]` you'll see the result as well :

```
>>> [i*weight for i in s]
[-1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60, -1.5608596215653603e+60]
```

Instead you can multiple directly :

```
>>> s = s*weight
>>> s
array([  2.70765983e+42,   3.04611731e+42,   3.21534605e+42,
         2.53843109e+42,   4.56917596e+42,   4.39994722e+42,
         2.19997361e+42,   5.75377713e+42,   6.43069209e+42,
         6.09223461e+42,   7.27683579e+42,   7.10760705e+42,
         8.12297948e+42,   8.46143696e+42,   9.30758066e+42,
         9.64603814e+42,   1.18460117e+43,   1.13383255e+43,
         1.09998681e+43,   1.43844428e+43,   1.67536452e+43,
         1.59075015e+43,   1.52305865e+43,   1.89536188e+43,
         2.13228211e+43,   2.19997361e+43,   2.40304810e+43,
         2.03074487e+43])
```

Comment: The NumPy result that you quote is incorrect (all the numbers are the same!). I would have expected a correct result (like in chw21's answer).

Comment: @EOL Yes sure it was a wrong copy! thanks for reminding!

Comment: `s[:]` does not "create a Python list object" (you can try it). Instead, it returns a view of the `s` array (which indeed contains some integer type).

Comment: Thanks. It's almost correct, now; the following should be fixed too: `s[:]` does not "create" a NumPy array object: as I was writing, it returns a *view*. No memory copy is performed (which is why assigning to it does modify `s`).

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to make the multiplication in `python` and not in `numpy`. Not only is `numpy` faster, but it also works better.

What you are trying to do creates a `python list`, which it then tries to copy into the `numpy array` element wise.

Instead just use

```
x = x * weight
```

and you're fine.

EOL doubted that this works, so here's what I just did on my computer:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2014, 19:03:52)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy import array
>>> x = array([ 16,  18,  19,  15,  27,  26,  13,  34,  38,  36,  43,  42,  48,
...     50,  55,  57,  70,  67,  65,  85,  99,  94,  90, 112, 126, 130,
...    142, 120])
>>> weight = 1.692287392646066e+41
>>> x = x * weight
>>> x
array([  2.70765983e+42,   3.04611731e+42,   3.21534605e+42,
         2.53843109e+42,   4.56917596e+42,   4.39994722e+42,
         2.19997361e+42,   5.75377713e+42,   6.43069209e+42,
         6.09223461e+42,   7.27683579e+42,   7.10760705e+42,
         8.12297948e+42,   8.46143696e+42,   9.30758066e+42,
         9.64603814e+42,   1.18460117e+43,   1.13383255e+43,
         1.09998681e+43,   1.43844428e+43,   1.67536452e+43,
         1.59075015e+43,   1.52305865e+43,   1.89536188e+43,
         2.13228211e+43,   2.19997361e+43,   2.40304810e+43,
         2.03074487e+43])
>>>
```

Comment: It does work for me. Please enlighten us what you think is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I had done `x *= weight` first, which resulted in an error. Then I did `x = x*weight`, and the result is wrong, in this case (because `x.dtype` is `int64` instead of `float64`).

Answer (score 1):

Please be reminded that the `numpy.ndarray` instance `x`, once created, will be assigned a unique type for the underlying data stored.  This is quite unlike a Python native list, which is something like an array that contains references to arbitrary, duck-typed Python objects.

Subsequent in-place modification of the underlying array data (in this case a slice assignment, i.e. syntactic sugar that actually calls the `__setitem__` method) will make attempts to cast values into the storage type.  In this case, the array `x` has integers, but the float values computed at the RHS of the assignment are too large to be cast into integers, causing integer overflow.

It could have worked if instead you had created the array with a suitable float type.  In pseudo-Python:

```
# Type for the storage of x explicitly set when creating it.
x = numpy.array([ whatever integer literals ... ], dtype=numpy.float64)
# Assignment succeeds.
x[:] = [ some list of floats ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the whole array with the factor in a single operation, there is no need to multiply the individual elements (that's the point of `numpy`):

```
>>> x = array([ 16,  18,  19,  15,  27,  26,  13,  34,  38,  36,  43,  42,  48,
...     50,  55,  57,  70,  67,  65,  85,  99,  94,  90, 112, 126, 130,
...    142, 120])
>>> weight = 1.692287392646066e+41
>>> x * weight
array([  2.70765983e+42,   3.04611731e+42,   3.21534605e+42,
         2.53843109e+42,   4.56917596e+42,   4.39994722e+42,
         2.19997361e+42,   5.75377713e+42,   6.43069209e+42,
         6.09223461e+42,   7.27683579e+42,   7.10760705e+42,
         8.12297948e+42,   8.46143696e+42,   9.30758066e+42,
         9.64603814e+42,   1.18460117e+43,   1.13383255e+43,
         1.09998681e+43,   1.43844428e+43,   1.67536452e+43,
         1.59075015e+43,   1.52305865e+43,   1.89536188e+43,
         2.13228211e+43,   2.19997361e+43,   2.40304810e+43,
         2.03074487e+43])
```

Comment: This is the idea, but it does not fully answer the question: `x` should be modified. Warning: there is a gotcha.

Comment: Why don't you write your own answer where everything is correct and there is no gotcha, I would be happy to learn something.

Comment: An answer is not a comment, that's why: they serve a different purpose (besides, there is already a good answer). The gotcha is that updating `x`, as in the question, cannot be done with `x *= weight`.